# Bootstrap Popover issue

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the following code for displaying image as a popover

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="C:\Users\zj9\Desktop\dist\Page\assets\js\jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="C:\Users\zj9\Desktop\dist\Page\assets\js\bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
    <script src="C:\Users\zj9\Desktop\dist\Page\assets\js\bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $( document ).ready(function() {
        var img = '<img src="https://si0.twimg.com/a/1339639284/images/three_circles/twitter-bird-white-on-blue.png" />';
        $("#blob").popover({ title: 'Look!  A bird image!', content: img });    
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="#" id="blob" class="btn large primary" rel="popover" style="margin-top: 300px">hover for popover</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

But the popover never gets displayed.
I have used the absolute paths just to make sure that this not path issue, will change that.
I have no experience of html or java script coding, any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the closing ');' for your javascript block. This results in the popover not being registered on the link.

Here's the [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/theoutlander/CPqcL/). Also, note that I've added the trigger: 'hover' and html: true attributes so that the popover shows when you hover and your image renders instead of showing text.

```
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    var img = '<img src="https://si0.twimg.com/a/1339639284/images/three_circles/twitter-bird-white-on-blue.png" />';
  $("#blob").popover({ title: 'Look!  A bird image!', content: img, trigger: 'hover', html: true });    
});
```

Comment: For cases like this an IDE like Dreamweaver helps a lot with syntax errors.

Comment: @Nick Karnik My popover image on the link gets out fro the window, I mean I have mentioned the placement = right, but it only displays half of the image as half image gets outside window, do you have a idea how can i resolve this

Comment: @Zohaib - You need to make CSS changes. Check the updated fiddle for the CSS fix. You might need to apply an appropriate fix for your case though. Also, ensure the aspect ratio is maintained. This example should get you started.

Comment: Oops, just realized that I forgot to set the new changes as base. If you didn't see the fix, try the link again @ http://jsfiddle.net/theoutlander/CPqcL/